# CPP file extension not working properly as a email attachment

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm new to C++ and am using Visual Studio 2015 to compile my codes as that is the compiler I was told to use for school work.  I opened up my cpp file from the email that I attached it to prior to sending to ensure that it opens and runs the way it supposed to, the file was able to open but the start without debug or start with debugging options are not available to use.

I then attached it as a vcxproj and it did everything it is supposed to do. I would be ok with sending the attachment as vcxproj file extension as it runs properly (can open up and the start without debug or start with debugging options are available and can be used to debug) but this is a homework assignment and the professor insists that I send it as a cpp extension.

What can I do to the cpp file to ensure that when it is opened up from an email attachment the user can select and use the start without debugging option?

Comment: `.vcxproj` files don't actually contain code, so you need to send `.cpp`.  The fact that you weren't able to use a .cpp file is probably because you needed to create a new project and add your file to it. Don't worry about it and just send the .cpp, your prof will figure it out.

Comment: I *really* don't see what using email as transport for a file has anything to do with C++. C++ source code is just text - same as any other text file. Sending it through email doesn't change the contents. What's the real problem here?